# GUI Update with multiple Backgroundworker C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, backgroundworker

Here i'm using multiple `backgroundworker`s to do one network related operation.Basically its a process of checking the user is registered with my page or not. I'm having nearly 1000 accounts to check, hence i'm using `datagridview` to import users and fetch the username from same for checking purpose. My code working fine and displays the result, But the problem is when updating the status in `datagridview` its not that much effective. In that long process method i used to set status text for every process of method, like `login process started` `logged in` `failed to login` .But `Backgroundworker` does not updating the status column. It displaying the status after all `backgroundworker` completes only. Can anyone give me an idea for how to update the status for each account ?? 
thanks in advance

It my code:

```
int threadNum;
    public  BackgroundWorker bcheker;
    private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (wbcheckStatus == WorkerStatus.NotStarted || wblogcheckStatus == WorkerStatus.Completed)
        {
            threadNum = -1;
            SetControlsStatus(ProgramStatus.BChecking);
            toolStripButton2.Image = aTumblr.Properties.Resources.control_stop;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                bcheker = new BackgroundWorker();
                bcheker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bcheker_dowork);
                bcheker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bchecker_completed);
                bcheker.ProgressChanged +=bcheker_ProgressChanged;
                bcheker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                bcheker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                bcheker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            threadNum = 10000;
            bcheker.CancelAsync();
            SetControlsStatus(ProgramStatus.BlogChecking);
        }
    }       
    public void bcheker_dowork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!bcheker.CancellationPending)
        {
            int rownum = Interlocked.Increment(ref threadNum);
            if (rownum >= bchecktableModel.Rows.Count)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            BlogChecker bc = new BlogChecker(bchecktableModel[rownum, 1].Text, bchecktableModel[rownum, 2]);
            bc.check();                
            wblogcheckStatus = WorkerStatus.Running;

        }
        if (bcheker.CancellationPending)
        {
            wblogcheckStatus = WorkerStatus.Completed;
            SetControlsStatus(ProgramStatus.BCheckingDone);

        }
    }

    public void bcheker_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void bchecker_completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (threadNum == bchecktableModel.Rows.Count+1)
        {
            SetControlsStatus(ProgramStatus.BCheckingDone);

            wblogcheckStatus = WorkerStatus.Completed;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It looks like you have an issue of multiple handlers registering to the DoWorkEvent.
I am not sure what is happening, but I would check How many time the `bcheker_dowork` method is being called.

In order to report about your progress, use the [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) method.

```
public void bcheker_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Update your progress here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your DoWork() method, you shouldn't be using "bcheker" as that will simply refer to the last BackgroundWorker created.  Instead, cast the sender parameter to a local BackgroundWorker variable and use that.